# Using methods with parameters

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, messagebox

I would like to use a method, that creates a message box:

```
public class Layout
{
    public void MBox(string msgText, string msgCaption, MessageBoxButtons msgButton, MessageBoxIcon msgIcon)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msgText, msgCaption, msgButton, msgIcon);
    }
}
```

Now, I try to open it by using the following code:

```
Layout _layout = new Layout();
_layout.MBox("Hello", "Hello again", OK, None);
```

Unfortunately, the application does not know "OK" and "None". What is my mistake? Could you please help me? Thanks in advance. Kind regards! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the type:

```
_layout.MBox("Hello", "Hello again", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
```

Additionally you could use default parameters to shorten the default case:

```
public void MBox(string msgText, string msgCaption, 
    MessageBoxButtons msgButton = MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon msgIcon = MessageBoxIcon.None)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msgText, msgCaption, msgButton, msgIcon);
}
```

The you can leave that two parameters out if they are `Ok` and `None`:

```
_layout.MBox("Hello", "Hello again");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `MessageBoxButton.OK` and `MessageBoxIcon.None`

[MessageBoxButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an enumeration of possible buttons to display in a messagebox. The same goes for [MessageBoxIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).